# Windows Store Apps - Privacy Policy - Share Contract . What should include?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-store-apps, privacy

Do I have to write something about the share contract into the app's privacy policy?
I made an app what is shares a user created image. For example in email or any share compatible app. If I have to write about, what is that exactly? At now I wrote that:

```
This Pricacy Policy covers your use of this application. 

The application does not collect, store, or share any 
personal information, or anything related to your device. We do not collect any
statistics, trends, neither do we track user movements.

This app allows you to launch the Windows Store for 'Rate and Review' or 
check the developer's orther applications. For details regarding the information
stored by the Windows Store, please read the privacy policy of that application.

This app allows you to open several web pages. The URLs from the 
web pages and also content of the pages might be saved by the internet 
browser on your device. For details regarding the information stored by 
these application, please read the privacy policy of the internet browser
on your device.
```

Any other Idea for safety sake? :)

The full text is [here](http://krekkon.wordpress.com/privacy-policy-personal-love-postcards/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't have to mention anything in the privacy policy about the share contract you're using.

When the user is using the Share Contract to share an image with someone or another app, that's a action that's initiated by the user itself, so he is aware of what he's doing.

The privacy policy is to inform the user if you're doing things from code which is not visible to the user. For example: If you track what the user is clicking and storing that on your own server, that are things that should be in the privacy policy.

Comment: So I take a link into the text, with highlight then is ok.
And if the user clicks to a logo of my other app and the store is launched with the page of that app. Is that ok? I think is obvius for clicking a logo with "My other apps" text will launches store, but the users (?)